# Scan input of bits from user

Tags: c

i wanted to know what is the best way to scan a input of.. lets say 16 bits from user.(exp: [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 ...])
i will use short int for that.

lets say that everyone of the bits stand for some property.
and i want that the user will be able to give me the input (some permutation of the the bits) by 2 ways:

first way: all of the 16 bits initialized with zero's, the user will give me the spots of the bits that he want to turn on:

> short int a=0;  (look like [000000....0])
>
> lets say user choose 3, 5

so, i know i can make a mask initialized with zero exept the requested place (which will be 1) like this:

> short int mask=0x1;
> mask<<=3;
>
> a|=mask;

and after that same thing with a mask that represent the fifth bit.
but is there a better way for doint that ?

the seconed question is, say i want to scan from the user the string that represent the requested permutation. (exp: 01101010100..)
how should i do that ?
the syntex is important to me here..  what should i write in the scanf ? etc.
thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe the first way is better. User wouldn't like to handle binary data. Your first way is clean and readable.

Comment: 2ndQ : use `strtoul` or `strtoull(input_string, NULL, 2);`

Comment: I would go with a hexadecimal representation of the 16 bits. Use short int a = (short int)strtol(hexastring, NULL, 16)

Comment: Why binary data? What kind of an app is this? Can't you provide some user-friendly names for these flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the syntax of the 2 inputs is different, allow both.

```
// pseudo code
fgets(buffer,...);
if (IsSyntax1(buffer)) {
  a = ProcesssPerSyntax1(buffer, a);
else if (IsSyntax2(buffer)) {
  a = ProcesssPerSyntax2(buffer, a);
else Error();
```

Example syntax parser

```
char *endptr;
// looking for 16-digit binary number
unsigned long tmp = strtoul(buffer, &endptr, 2);
if (endptr == &buffer[16] && *endptr == '\n') {
  a = (short) tmp;
}
else {
  // Search for comma separated 0-15 offsets
  char *p = buffer;
  unsigned mask = 0;
  do {
    unsigned long index = strtoul(p, &endptr, 10);
    if (index >= 16) return fail;
    if ((*endptr != ',') && (*endptr != '\n')) return fail;
    if (endptr == p) return fail;
    mask |= 1U << (unsigned) index; 
    p = endptr + 1;
  } while (*endptr == ',');
  a = mask;
}
```

[Edit]
Should use strtoul() vs. strtol() to deal with 16-bit `int/unsigned` as hinted by @BLUEPIXY comment.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking buffer length before converting it ?

Comment: @Groo (I assume you refer to `strtol(buffer, &endptr, 2)`)  Checking the buffer length beforehand (and not checking the value of `endptr`) would catch only a subset of illegal inputs.  Checking the value of `endptr` afterwards, well determines valid syntax.  Maybe I am missing your concern?

Comment: Actually, I was referring to `&buffer[16]` but that's just address offset, not a read operation. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not worry about the memory usage (anyways, it is not much) you can take input as a string, and  then use `strtol` (from `stdlib.h`) or similar functions to convert it to an integer.

I suggest `strtol` because you can specify the base of conversion here.

In your first method, I see one limitation that if number of set bits (`1`s) are large then it will be inconvenient for user.